# Unexpected Animation Behavior

Tags: java, android

[image]

My situation:

1. Target SDK: 2.2
2. Target Animation Effect: Path menu. When you swipe to the right, the upper view is animated to the right, revealing the underneath menu view.

My XML structure:

```
<Parent Relative Layout>    //background color is white
    <Upper Linear Layout>
    <Bottom Linear Layout>  //background color is red
</Parent Relative Layout>
```

My 2 approaches to animate the upper linear layout:

1. Official pre-honeycomb **TranslateAnimation** method, with **FillAfter** set to true.
2. Un-offcial pre-honycomb **ObjectAnimator.ofFloat** method through [nineoldandroids](http://nineoldandroids.com)

What I expect with both these 2 approaches:

1. Animation is triggered
2. Upper linear layout is gradually animated to the right
3. Underneath linear layout (red background) is gradually revealed

What I actually see with both these 2 approaches:

1. Animation is triggered
2. Upper linear layout is gradually animated to the right
3. Parent relative layout (white background) is gradually revealed
4. Underneath linear layout is no where to be seen

I've no idea what I am doing wrong here. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I need to dynamically create this **Upper Linear Layout** and add it to the **Parent Relative Layout**, instead of declaring it statically in the xml. When I do swipe animation again, the underneath **bottom linear layout** will appear.